# Long method execution within Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have a java project, with a method that parses a file.
When I execute it from Junit it takes about 120 milliseconds to finish.

When I add this project build path of Eclipse RCP plugin project, and execute same method
it takes 40000 milliseconds to complete.

Input to method is exactly the same also the output.

What can be done regarding that?

Comment: Code in an RCP/plugin does not normally take any longer to run. You need to do more investigation in to this problem.

Comment: I guess this is true, but can't understand from where to start.

Comment: Is it really the execution of the method that you are measuring or also the calling of the method? Dependent on the underlying framework (JUnit vs. OSGi) the result can differ.

Comment: the measure is done within the method.

Comment: does your method make any calls outside itself? UI updates for example? Are you able to post the method in the question? Have you tried reducing the method to a MCVE?